# Trigger on same table in oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have the table employee_leave :

```
  /
```

I need to create a trigger so that when a manager ( is_manager='Y') is deleted from this table, the manager's subordinate/employee with the managers employee_id as his/her employee_manager_id, should have employee_manager_id set as null on deletion.

How can i write this and what kind of triggers would help the same table would be updated after deletion.

Comment: Why do you actually need this?  It is easy enough to check if a parent reference does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a trigger, or any code at, all for this. Create a FK from EMPLOYEE_MANAGER_ID to EMPLOYEE_MANAGER_ID with on delete set null option.

```
    CREATE TABLE  "EMPLOYEE_LEAVE" 
       (    "EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "EMPLOYEE_NAME" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "EMPLOYEE_EMAIL" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "EMPLOYEE_MANAGER_ID" NUMBER, 
        "EMPLOYEE_USERNAME" VARCHAR2(400), 
        "EMPLOYEE_LEAVE_NORMAL" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "EMPLOYEE_LEAVE_LOP" NUMBER, 
        "EMPLOYEE_IS_MANAGER" CHAR(1) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "EMPLOYEE_IS_ADMIN" CHAR(1) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "EMPLOYEE_CONTACT_NO" VARCHAR2(100), 
        "EMPLOYEE_PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(100), 
         CONSTRAINT "EMPLOYEE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("EMPLOYEE_ID")
      USING INDEX  ENABLE

        , constraint empmgr_2_emp foreign key (employee_manager_id) 
          references employee_leave(employee_id) on delete set null
);
```

Comment: That is a data problem. You have or row having a employee_manager_id value that is NOT in the table. Try " select * from employee_leave el1 
  where el1.employee_manager_id 
    and not exists (select null 
                      from employee_leave el2 
                     where el2.employee_manager_id = el1.employee_id 
                   ) ;

Comment: earlier employee_is_manager was set to not null, so i made it nullable. despite that also i am getting same error.

Comment: That column has nothing to do with the error.  The column employee_manager_Id contains a value that is not in column employee_id.